# Progress bar height

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, progress-bar

I try to integrate progress bar in my layout. The progress bar cannot fix all screen size. I try to tune the height many times. But no one is suitable for every device. So how can I fix the progress bar height in all screen size.
`main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gray_bg"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg_pushup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha="0.7"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:src="@drawable/image_push_up"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/counter_button_close" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_sound"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/counter_button_mute" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="START PUSH-UPS"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_pushup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt_start"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@drawable/counter_bg"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_pushup_count"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:textSize="36sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_pushup_timer"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
                android:layout_centerVertical="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="0:00"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="#b5b4ad"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="75"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_circular"
            android:secondaryProgress="100" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_shade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:src="@drawable/counter_shade" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_question_mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/progressBar2"

            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/question_mark" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Progress bar**
[image]

Please help me to design the xml for all screen size device.

Comment: how about using 0dp in height and giving the weight to the ProgressBar! it will try its best to adopt itself in every screensize

Comment: Where can set the weight? I can't find weight in progress bar attribute.

Comment: lemme show the solution

Answer (score 0):

putting the progress bar inside a container and then doing the size will work fine! try like this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_weight = 1>
         <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="75"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/style_circular"
            android:secondaryProgress="100" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: My layout has many item. The progress bar is set the centre of the layout.  So I cannot set match_parent for height

Comment: progress bar is in between the layouts! well I thought you might be using it using FrameLayout for showing it above the layouts! please show some of your rendered screen so I could figure out the solution easily

Comment: I post the picture again. The left top corner and right top corner has image view. Then below has text view. The centre has progress bar. Two text view are centre of the progress bar. A text view, 2 image views below of the progress bar.

Comment: please provide detailed xml of your design that you are trying to make! bcz here I can see from your picture that it is easily achieved using FrameLayout power!

Comment: I posted my xml and update the picture clearly I want.